# Wrong multidiemnsional-array initialization trying to build the pascal triangle (JAVA)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, initialization, pascals-triangle

I am trying to write a class that creates an object of a pascal triangle using multidimensional arrays. Now i do have everything in place (at least i think so) except for the correct Initialization of the array. My program reads as follow:

```
class Pascal{

//Object variables
int size;
int[][] pascal;

Pascal(int size){ //Constructor

    this.size = size; //Defines how many rows/columns the triangle has.
    pascal = new int[size][];

    //Allocation of the arrays 
    for(int i=0;i<pascal.length;i++)
        pascal[i] = new int[i+1];

    pascal[0][0] = 1; //the tip of the triangle is always one. Also you need a value to start with.


    //Initialisation of the elements
    for(int x=0;x<pascal.length;x++){
        for(int y=0;y<pascal[x].length;y++){

            if(x>0){

                if(y==0 || y == (pascal[x].length)-1)
                    pascal[x][y] = 1; //Initialisation of the first and last element of the actual array x

                else
                    pascal[x-1][y-1] = pascal[x-1][y] + pascal[x-1][y-1];//Initialisation of all elements in between

            }
        }
    }

}


//The print method needed to display the pascal triangle
void print(){
    for(int i=0;i<pascal.length;i++){
        for(int k=pascal.length;k>i;k--)
            System.out.print(" ");
        for(int j=0;j<pascal[i].length;j++)
            System.out.print(pascal[i][j]+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}


//main function
public static void main(String... args){
    Pascal p = new Pascal(5); //example triangle consisting of 5 rows total
    p.print();
}
}
```

The output in this particiular example (new Pascal(5);) should be:

```
    1
   1 1
  1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

And yet it is:

```
    1
   2 1
  1 1 1
 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 1
```

I know the problem must be somewhere in the array initialization part of the code and it's probably a simple mistake, but starring at the monitor doesn't get me anywhere anymore :/

Just in case you don't just want to give me the answer: 
From my understanding the array element pascal[1][0] should be 1 instead of 2, because when the for-loops value x is 1 and value y is 0 the if-condition if( y==0 || y==pascal[x].length-1) should apply thus setting pascal[1][0] = 1.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor, when initializing the 2D array, in the `else`, your assignment is incorrect.  You want to initialize the current element, but the left hand side is incorrect (and inconsistent with the `if`):

```
pascal[x-1][y-1] = pascal[x-1][y] + pascal[x-1][y-1];
```

Try the `[x][y]` element itself.

```
pascal[x][y] = pascal[x-1][y] + pascal[x-1][y-1];
```

Making only this change, I get the correct output:

```
     1 
    1 1 
   1 2 1 
  1 3 3 1 
 1 4 6 4 1
```

Comment: i got the same just this second. must be the time here. thanks for the quick answer. that question really was a waste of webspace -_-